# How to declare a json string correctly?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

So I tested two ways of declaring a json string:

1:

```
json = "{'name': 'ajsie'}";
obj = JSON.parse(json); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

2:

```
json = '{"name": "ajsie"}';
obj = JSON.parse(json); // Worked!
```

What is the problem with the first one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Single quotes are not a valid quote character for strings. From http://www.json.org/: "A value can be a string in double quotes..."

Answer (score 2):

[json.org](http://json.org/) defines a string to use " instead of '.  That's my guess.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://www.json.org/

Strings in JSON object must be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Okay, when I run 'asd' in Chrome it automatically converts it to "asd". Therefore I thought that was okay.

Comment: Yeah, it's a tricky error @weng. One would think that single and double quotes are interchangeable as everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.json.org/ is a great reference for JSON. Apparently you have to use double quotes for strings in JSON. I learned something new today too. :)

Answer (score -1):

`{ 'key' : 'val' }` is not properly formatted json.